# Upgrading from Flex 3.0 to Flex 3.6 - Custom Combobox getting TypeError in super.commitProperties()

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am working on upgrading Flex 3.0 application to Flex 3.6 SDK. The application has custom controls for input text, combo-boxes, etc. When I click on the combo-box I get exception when super.commitProperties() is called. This works fine with Flex 3.0 SDK.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at mx.controls::ComboBox/destroyDropdown()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\ComboBox.as:1681]
    at mx.controls::ComboBox/styleChanged()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\ComboBox.as:1177]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/setBorderColorForErrorString()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:5048]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/commitProperties()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:6033]
    at mx.controls::ComboBase/commitProperties()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\ComboBase.as:993]
    at mx.controls::ComboBox/commitProperties()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\ComboBox.as:1291]
    at com.hanover.utility.controls.autotestcontrols::AutotestComboBox/commitProperties()[C:\App\Control\PLCustomComboBox.as:59]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:5966]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:539]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:689]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateNow()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:748]
    at mx.controls::ComboBox/displayDropdown()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\ComboBox.as:1638]
    at mx.controls::ComboBox/downArrowButton_buttonDownHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\ComboBox.as:1796]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:9590]
    at mx.controls::Button/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::buttonPressed()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\Button.as:2504]
    at mx.controls::Button/mouseDownHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\Button.as:2750]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:9590]
    at mx.controls::ComboBase/textInput_mouseEventHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\ComboBase.as:1384]
```

PLCustomCombobox.as pseudo-source with line # 59 indicated below

```
package com
{
    import com.name.utility.events.PLControlEvent;
    import com.name.utility.managers.ComboToolTipManager;

    import flash.events.Event;

    import mx.controls.ComboBox;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    [Event(name="controlInitComplete", type="com.events.PLControlEvent")]

    [Event(name="plusControlValueChanged", type="com.name.utility.events.PLControlEvent")]

    public class PLControlComboBox extends ComboBox 
                                implements IPLControlControl
    {
        /**
         * A flag that indicates whether the control need to refresh.
         */     
        protected var isNeedRefresh:Boolean = false;

        /**
         * A flag that indicates whether the value of control is changed.
         */     
        protected var isValueChanged:Boolean = false;

        /**
         *  Constructor.
         */
        public function PLControlComboBox()
        {
            super();
            this.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, onCreationComplete);
        }

        /**
         * @private
         * override commitProperties for avoid dispatch event many times.
         */     
        override protected function commitProperties():void
        {
            super.commitProperties(); // <---- line # 59 is here

            if(isNeedRefresh)
            {
                this.dispatchEvent(new PLControlEvent(PLControlEvent.VALUE_CHANGED));
                isNeedRefresh = false;
            }

            if(isValueChanged)
            {
                this.dispatchEvent(new Event("PLControlComboboxChanged"));
                isValueChanged = false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Add item's tooltip.
         * @private
         */
        override public function set measuredWidth(value:Number):void
        {
            super.measuredWidth = value;
            if(collection && collection.length > 0)
            {
                ComboToolTipManager.showItemToolTip(this);
            }
        }
        protected function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            this.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, onCreationComplete);
            this.dispatchEvent(new PLControlEvent(PLControlEvent.INIT_COMPLETE));
        }

        public function checkValidity():void
        {
            if(_required && dataProvider && dataProvider.length > 0 && _defaultItemIndex == selectedIndex)
            {
                _validity   = false;
                errorString = "please select one";
            }
            else
            {
                _validity   = true;
                errorString = "";
            }
        }

        // ======================================
        // public function
        // ======================================
        private function itemChanged():void
        {
            isNeedRefresh = true;
            isValueChanged = true;
            checkValidity();
        }

        // ======================================
        // properties
        // ======================================

        private var _required:Boolean       = false;
        private var _validity:Boolean       = false;
        private var _defaultItemIndex:int   = 0;

        public function get required():Boolean
        {
            return _required;
        }

        [Inspectable(defaultValue=false, category="Other")]
        public function set required(value:Boolean):void
        {
            _required       = value;
            isNeedRefresh   = true;
            checkValidity();
        }

        [Bindable("PLControlComboboxChanged")]
        public function get controlValue():Object
        {
            return this.selectedIndex;
        }

        public function set controlValue(value:Object):void
        {
            if(value is Number)
            {
                this.selectedIndex = int(value);
                itemChanged();
            }
        }

        /**
         * @copy IPLControlControl#validity
         */
        public function get validity():Boolean
        {
            return _validity;
        }

        /**
         * @copy IPLControlControl#type
         */
        public function get type():String
        {
            return PLControlTypeList.CONTROL_TYPE_COMBOBOX;
        }

        /**
         * If required is true, the default Item can not be selected.
         */
        public function get defaultItemIndex():int
        {
            return _defaultItemIndex;
        }

        [Inspectable(defaultValue=0, type="Number", category="Other")]
        public function set defaultItemIndex(index:int):void
        {
            _defaultItemIndex = index;
            isNeedRefresh   = true;
            checkValidity();
        }

        /**
         * Override for check validity.
         */
        override public function set selectedIndex(value:int):void
        {
            super.selectedIndex = value;
            itemChanged();
        }

        /**
         * Override for check validity.
         */
        override public function set selectedItem(value:Object):void
        {
            super.selectedItem = value;
            itemChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Its coming from mx.controls.Comboxbox line # 1681 because tween is null.

```
private function destroyDropdown():void
    {
        if (inTween)
            tween.endTween();//<---- exception on this line

        displayDropdown(false, null, false);
    }
```

Any suggestions of why this could be happening?

Comment: There were a lot of changes to the ComboBox implementation in 3.5.  We had to rework our AutoComplete ComboBox component significantly due to these.  You're probably going to need to rework your custom ComboBox extension.  But, you haven't provided us with nearly enough information to help you debug.  I think we'd need to see your extended custom code. I'd look at line 59 of PLCustomComboBox.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Updated with component source. line # 59 is call to super.commitProperties()

Comment: May I ask why you would want to upgrade from one legacy SDK to another? I have to admit I haven't touched Flex 3 since many years, so I may be overlooking something, but from where I stand that seems like a pointless operation.

Comment: We need to use Flex 3.6 features (unhandled exceptions) thats why.

Comment: I think @RIAstar meant to ask; why not go all the way up to Flex 4.6 or Apache Flex 4.8?  And, unfortunately, super.commitProperties may be the line in your code that triggers the error; but it sure doesn't help us guess the cause.  :-(

Comment: Not my call to make as its a big application and would be big $$$ to move it over to Flex 4

Comment: @VineetBhatia I'm not sure why the cost of moving to Flex 3.6 would be different than the cost of moving to 4.6; assuming you stick with the MX components.  All the MX Components are in still the framework and you aren't obligated to use the new Spark Architecture.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that. But why would we use Flex 4 if we are not using Spark architecture? Also won't we need to upgrade from Flex Builder 3 to FB4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed in Apache Flex 4.10 and above, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33382.

If using an older SDK you could monkey patch mx:ComboBox like so adding the "&& tween" check:

```
private function destroyDropdown():void
{
    if (inTween && tween)
        tween.endTween();

    displayDropdown(false, null, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks will try that out. Link to changed file - http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/flex/sdk/branches/develop/frameworks/projects/mx/src/mx/controls/ComboBox.as?revision=1442453&view=co&pathrev=1442453